# PIPESTATUS from commands in $(...|...)

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe

How to read `${PIPESTATUS[0]` of a command, when a variable is set in current shell? Is there a way to pass it to current shell somehow?

I am setting variable `MAIL=$(ldapsearch.... | find_for_mail)` and want to be sure if `ldapsearch` did not failed itself before I decide that mail attribute does not really exists in LDAP.

```
$ true | false
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
0 1
$ Z=$(true | false)
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
1                        <--- why 1?
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}

$ Z=$(true | false;echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]})
$ echo $Z
0 1
$ Z=$(true | false;C="${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}")
$ echo $C

$ Z=$(true | false;export C="${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}")
$ echo $C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `export` exports variables as environment variables from the parent to the child process, not the other way around. If you are only interested in one of the exit codes you can use this:

```
$ Z=$(false | true; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thank you, it does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it on Linux would be to pass the data using a temporary file (`<<<` happens to use a temporary file).

```
{
  output=$(cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3; printf '%s\n' "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" > /dev/fd/3)
  readarray -t cmdsubst_pipe_status <&3
} 3<<< ''
printf '%s\n' "cmd1's status: ${cmdsubst_pipe_status[0]}"
```